# How to get partial match as well as full match using hibernate search

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =Search.getFullTextEntityManager(emanager);
QueryBuilder qb=fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
Query statusNotArchieved = qb.keyword().onField("name").matching("John Cena").createQuery();
```

> Now i Should get Results where result should contain person name
>   containing John Cena as well as any phrase that contains either John 
>   Or Cena Separately. So if there are three  rows for the Person name 
>   containing {"John Cena","John micheal","Micheal Cena"} i want all the 
>   results prioritizing John Cena as first Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you gave should behave exactly like you described: any document containing "John" or "Cena" will be matched, with those matching both being given a higher score and thus appearing near the top of the results.

That is, assuming you enabled analysis on field "name", which is the case by default.

If you are getting a different behavior, please give more information:

- The full code of your `Person` entity
- The full code used to build the query (you only gave the beginning.
- A short description of the results you are getting: the documents, their order and the content of their "name" field.